# ionic $cordovaGeolocation always requests permission for location access

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am running ionic and the ngCordova geolocation wrapper.

Here is a snippet from a controller using the plugin:

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                $cordovaGeolocation
                    .getCurrentPosition({timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false})
                    .then(permissionGranted)
                    .catch(permissionNotGranted)
                    .then(loadGmap)
                    .catch(handleGmapLoadError);
            });
```

I run my app using:

`ionic run ios --device`

As the app comes up, I am asked permission to access the location of the phone as expected.  I acknowledge it and my controller loads my location in google maps.  I see the permission set in my ios settings reflect the setting made.  when I open the app the second time, it asks again. This was unexpected behavior.

Most apps don't ask again and again.  Has any one else seen this behavior and know what I should do?

Answer (score -1):

you can try to add the permission in the config file (app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml)
`<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
</feature>`

and in the(app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml)

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`

Comment: Anas, will those additions help me for iOS? I am currently not targeting android.